# SQLAlchemy Concurrency and Queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a number of separate machines, each of which uses a separate instantiation of

`Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))`.

If machine A runs the code

```
session = Session()
session.add(Foo(pk=1))
session.commit()
```

what do I have to do ensure that when machine B runs the below code...

```
session = Session()
result = session.query(Foo).get(1)
```

... that `result` holds the new row of `Foo` that machine A created (assume that machine A's code ran first). I've had problems before where Session "A" commits an object but another Session "B" cannot find it in a query until I reinstantiate Session "B".

Comment: what isolation level are you running at?

Answer (score 0):

`scoped_session` wraps `Session` in a thread local storage object; if you're doing more work to handle threads, you might want to either refactor your code to use a single `scoped_session` instance for all threads, or use the result of `sessionmaker` directly, without wrapping it, again one for all threads, and call `Session()` for each thread.